# Вместо изображений на сайте тэги

Tags: python, html, django, ckeditor

Изучаю `python django` и добавил в `admin.py CKEditorUploadingWidget`, чтоб можно было через админку редактировать посты. Но при добавлении картинки через этот виджет, на самой странице `html` отображается только

```
<p>
  <img alt="" src="/media/uploads/2020/10/19/luqwlgow0dq.jpg" style="width: 295px; height: 413px;" />
</p>
```

Также некоторые знаки конвертируются в тэги и выводятся в таком виде.

Например, вместо `"привет"` идет `&quot;привет&quot;`. Пожалуйста помогите, в чем может быть причина, моя компетенция не позволяет мне найти ответ.

Уже добавлял в конфиг `CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;` но безуспешно.

Answer (score 0):

Короче, нужно было проэкранировать,в моем случае поставить фильтр safe в шаблон.